# Downloading Loadrunner vUser log files in the controller

Tags: loadrunner

Can I get all the vuser log files for a run into results folder on the controller ?
It seems to have some of the log files, but not all. 
If you select “Show Vuser Log” for a vuser without a log file – one is created. (Selecting from the run tab on the controller after the test has run)

I know the controller gets the info from the mdrv log files in the temp folder on the generator.

Is it possible to generate them all without selecting each user in turn ?
Nb: I know you can select “Show Vuser Log” for each group and status but that doesn’t generate all the log files, you have to select each in turn to generate the log ?

NB: I want to do this after a run has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the temp directory created on the load generator.  You can recover all of the logs from there if needed.

Side note: Every effort should be made to minimize logging during a test for this activity involves on of the classical four finite resource: Disk, CPU, Memory and Network. Disk writes are ring 0 (operating system concept) activity and must be handled immediately to the deference of any application CPU cycles.   So, you can saturate a load generator with small number of users logging heavily and distort the response times that are collected and reported.  This disk bias is but one of many reasons why performance testing tools often (as loadrunner does) load it's parameter files into memory at the beginning of the test

Comment: Thanks
Already getting log files from temp on generator. 

Wondered if I could download to the scenario results folder post test, bypassing the manual step.
(Not selecting every vuser log) 

Think the temp logs are for each mdrv.exe, they contain details for multiple users - I need to get session ids to help debug application server logs. - nb:I cant run vUsers as a seperate process, and I have reduced threads per process as much as I dare

Completely agree with the point about minimizing the logging, mdrv.exe abnormal termination errors are part of what got me to here